# how to return new record from graphql mutation instead of null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

I read through the apollo-server-tutorial and I'm trying to replicate it with only mongodb - no sqllite. I'm coming from meteor so I'm learning async & mongoose while I'm at it.

My mutation for addAuthor() works correctly (I see a new record in the DB) but graphiql returns null. How do I get it to return the expected fields?

```
mutation {
  addAuthor(firstName: "falieson", lastName:"p") {
    _id
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "addAuthor": null
  }
}
```

Schema: https://github.com/Falieson/apollo-server-tutorial-only-mongodb/blob/master/data/schema.js#L39

Resolver: https://github.com/Falieson/apollo-server-tutorial-only-mongodb/blob/master/data/resolvers.js#L38

Mongoose: https://github.com/Falieson/apollo-server-tutorial-only-mongodb/blob/master/data/models/mongoose.js#L51

Model: https://github.com/Falieson/apollo-server-tutorial-only-mongodb/blob/master/data/models/index.js#L7

Comment: when I console.log the return of the mutation resolver I get undefined, but when I console.log the res of the defaultReturn callback handler it happens after the mutation resolver returns. Therefore I think this is likely promise/async issue ... still would appreciate help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to have mongoose return a promise for the mutation. So my MongooseModel.create() changes from

```
const record = new this.collection(args)
return record.save(cb)
```

to using Promise

```
const record = new this.collection(args)
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   record.save((err, res) => {
      err ? reject(err): resolve(res)
   });
});
```

to using Async/Await

```
 async create(obj = {}) {
   const args = {
     ...this.defaultRecord(),
     ...obj
   }
   const record = new this.Collection(args)

   try {
     const savedRecord = await record.save()
     return savedRecord
   } catch (err) {
     handleError(err)
   }
 }
```

My mutation doesn't have to change at all, but my fixtures generator also has to be updated to use the Promise.then() chain.